# Why did Roman children call their father 'tata' instead of 'pappa'?

Tags: classical-latin, roman-culture

I was reading a text from Hans H. Øberg, and I saw in the text the following sentences:

> Noli dicere 'tatam' et 'mammam', Iuliola! Ea nomina a te audire nolumus. Ita loquuntur parvuli infantes, nec sermo infantium te decet. 'Patrem' et 'matrem' dicere oportet!

Those sentences told me that 'tata' was the definition of 'father'. But didn't Roman children call their father ''papa'?

If yes, why did they say tata instead of papa?

If no, where does the name 'papa' come from?

Comment: Can you explain why you chose *pappa* as a potential alternative? And although you are writing in English, what language *pappa* is from? I'm hoping that by answering these questions you'll straighten out the thinking that's behind your question.

Comment: Relevant: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/865/why-do-most-words-for-mother-across-languages-start-with-an-m-and-for-fa and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mama_and_papa

Comment: Tata is the only one word for father in Romanian. "Parinte" is parent meaning mother or father. So, strangely enough, tata and mama are the first words we learn :). I checked and in Latin, Greek or Czech this is not the main word for father. In Romanian it is not just main but the only one.

Comment: @user10832 Considering that Romanian is a daughter language of Latin, that makes a lot of sense. The formal word *pater* was forgotten and the common word *tata* was used instead. You get that in Russian, too, where *mama* is used regularly, and *mat'* sounds weird.

Comment: I thought "mamma" did not mean "mother", but "breast", whence "mammalia" (animals that have breasts, mammals).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, children *did* call their fathers *papa*, though it was not as common as *tata* was, at least we think.

Both names are inherited from Indo-European [as you can see](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/papa) and are even present in English: cf. paw or papa (also the origin of grampa) and dad or daddy.

[Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=papa), though, says that in English *papa* comes via French:

> **papa** n. "father," 1680s, from French *papa*, from Latin *papa*, originally a child's word, similar to Greek *pappa* (vocative) "o father," *pappas* "father," *pappos* "grandfather." The native word is *daddy*; first use of papa was in courtly speech, as a continental affectation, not used by common folk until late 18c.

For completeness' sake:

> **dad** n. recorded from c. 1500, but probably much older, from child's speech, nearly universal and probably prehistoric (compare Welsh *tad*, Irish *daid*, Czech, Latin, Greek *tata*, Lithuanian *tete*, Sanskrit *tatah*, all of the same meaning).

Comment: Is it safe to assume that Vatican leader's name is related to greek or latin word too? Curiously  today slavic languages use  papa as affection of child to father, while at least in case of Ukrainian and Russian just a hundred years ago "tyatya" or "tata" was a child  word. Contrary, in Japanese "tata" is mother

Comment: @Swift Yep, "pope" descends from "papa." Which is actually too bad because there's a pretty cool Latin word, [*popa*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/popa#Latin).

Comment: Explains  why in Russian pope is called papa to advantage of being used for puns, while second word, popa..  is.. "cushioning" word that means butt (well, like English "rump")

Comment: @Swift: In Japanese, "mother" is _haha_, for earlier (8th–16th Century, at least) _fafa_, and **possibly** pre-historic (as in, before any written records) _papa_. "Father" is _chichi_, which at some point in the past must have been _titi_. But _tata_ is not a kinship term in Japanese.